# How do I determine current GC settings used by Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection

I'm working on tuning our Rails stack which runs on Unicorn. I am now setting `RUBY_FREE_MIN`, `RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS` and `RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT`.

I've not found a way to confirm that these values are propagating from my configuration to the Ruby/Rails environment. Using `ENV['RUBY_FREE_MIN']` does not seem to expose the setting even when I explicitly set it when launching the Rails process so I don't think this is the way.

Is there a way inside of a Rails console to check the currently set values of these settings?

I've used `GC.stat` to see current statistics for garbage collection but have not see a way to get the settings.

Comment: I may partially answer my own question here... I realized that I wasn't launching my rails console form within the same environment that the startup script was. Once I did this, I was able to see the values for the garbage collection that I set using ENV['SETTING_NAME'].

This still doesn't allow me to see the values if I've not set them via environment variable. Is there a way to see these after they have propagated to the GC object in ruby?